# how can i configurate python 3.7 with odoo 13 in pycharm windows 8

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, python-3.7, odoo-13

i tried to use odoo 13 src with python 3.7.4 on windows 8, i configured pycharm

script path : D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\odoo-bin

parameters : -r odoo -w odoo --db_host=localhost --addons-path=D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\addons

and i installed python requirements but always odoo didn't work

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 56, in <module>
    from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\server.py", line 92, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\addons\calendar\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import controllers
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\addons\calendar\controllers\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import main
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\addons\calendar\controllers\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from odoo.api import Environment
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\odoo\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .tools.translate import _
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\odoo\tools\translate.py", line 21, in <module>
    from babel.messages import extract
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\babel\messages\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from babel.messages.catalog import *
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\babel\messages\catalog.py", line 15, in <module>
    from cgi import parse_header
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\cgi.py", line 39, in <module>
    from email.parser import FeedParser
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
ImportError: cannot import name '_has_surrogates' from 'email.utils' (C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\utils.py)
```

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/odoo_13_projects/odoo13/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\odoo\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\odoo\modules\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\odoo\modules\graph.py", line 10, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\odoo\tools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "D:\odoo_13_projects\odoo13\odoo\tools\misc.py", line 29, in <module>
    import werkzeug.utils
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py", line 218, in <module>
    from .serving import run_simple
  File "C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 59, in <module>
    import SocketServer as socketserver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'
```

can any one help me please

Comment: `SocketServer` is name for the module in Python2 code, are you sure there is not a mismatch of files? Odoo13 is fully Python3 code.

Comment: i use python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Can you use python3.6?
because I am already using odoo 13 with python3.6 and I can't see any problem.

I think in your case there will be library mismatch for SocketServer because in python3.7 package name is `socketserver`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I use two versions of python so I have to uncheck add content roots to PYTHONPATH and add source roots to PYTHONPATH in pycharm. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Do not use virtual interpreter  pythons
that is okey
check this configuration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpWGd.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).